# How to get quarterly data from monthly in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table where I am having monthly data like below.

Here my `AvgSpeedOfAnswer` column is calculated like this:

```
avg(SpeedOfAnswer)
```

Table:

| Date | AvgSpeedOfAnswerMonth |
| --- | --- |
| 7/1/2022 | 20.8 |
| 8/1/2022 | 22.6 |
| 9/1/2022 | 24.9 |

Now my requirement is I need to create a query where I can get quarterly data from above monthly table data.

I wrote a query like this:

```
SELECT
    'Quarterly' AS TrendType,
    DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, TrendStartdate), 0) AS TrendStartdate,
    SUM(AvgSpeedOfAnswer) 
FROM
    Month_Stats  
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, TrendStartdate), 0) 
ORDER BY 
    DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, TrendStartdate), 0)
```

I am not sure what should I need to take for `AvgSpeedOfAnswer`.

Is it `SUM(AvgSpeedOfAnswerMonth)` or `AVG(AvgSpeedOfAnswerMonth)` or `AVG(SUM(AvgSpeedOfAnswerMonth))`?

Could anyone please suggest?

Comment: In my opinion, you cannot calculate avg speed from month into a quarter, because it will not be correct. Instead you have to track the original distance / time and then recalculate AVG speed for each time period by doing SUM(distance) / SUM(time). Consider for example someone who drove 10000 miles one month and 10 minutes the next. If averaging the month separately and then averaging the speed, the second month will affect the speed far too much

Comment: And, SELECT FROM Something a JOIN Calendard b ON a.Date >= b.BeginDate AND a.Date <= b.EndDate GROUP BY ... etcc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned.
You need to use DATEPART

```
SELECT 
    'Quarterly' AS TrendType,
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Date), ((DATEPART(Q, Date) - 1) * 3) + 1, 1) AS TrendStartdate,
    AVG(AvgSpeedOfAnswerMonth) AS AvgSpeedOfAnswerQuarter
FROM 
    Month_Stats
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(Date),
    DATEPART(Q, Date)
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(Date),
    DATEPART(Q, Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use DATEPART and QUARTER

```
CREATE TABLE tabl11
    ([Date] datetime, [AvgSpeedOfAnswerMonth] DECIMAL(10,1))
;
    
INSERT INTO tabl11
    ([Date], [AvgSpeedOfAnswerMonth])
VALUES
    ('2022-07-01 02:00:00', 20.8),
    ('2022-08-01 02:00:00', 22.6),
    ('2022-09-01 02:00:00', 24.9)
;
```

```
3 rows affected
```

```
SELECT YEAR([Date]), DATEPART(QUARTER, [Date]), SUM([AvgSpeedOfAnswerMonth]) sum_quarterly FROM tabl11
GROUP BY YEAR([Date]),DATEPART(QUARTER, [Date])
```

| (No column name) | (No column name) | sum_quarterly |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 3 | 68.3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/P3L4E8dn)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need avg (AvgSpeedOfAnswerMonth) to get the quarterly average speed over the quarter. Sum(AvgSpeedOfAnswerMonth) and avg(sum(AvgSpeedOfAnswerMonth) give the same value, which is the sum of the quarterly values.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DATEPART function with parameter QUARTER, like

```
select 'Quarterly' as Quarterly, date as date from yourTable  
group by DATEPART(quarter, date)  
order by DATEPART(quarter, date)
```